# number generator show wrong segments on 7 segment display

Tags: arduino-uno, 7-segment

I created a program to show a random number on a 7 segment display. It shows a random number in the serial monitor but always shows the same segments 'a c d and g'. anyone know hopw to fix this without changing the base of the coding its for and exercise so i need to have most of the code like I wrote it.

```
int num_array[11][7] = {
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // 0
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 1
  { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, // 2
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, // 3
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // 4
  { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 }, // 5
  { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // 6
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 7
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // 8
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // 9
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};  //OFF

int buttonState = 0;
const int button = 12;
int randVal;
bool pressVal;
void num_Write(int);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(button);
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    turnOff();
    pressVal = false;

  }
  else
  {
    if (pressVal == false)
    {
      int pin = 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
      {
        digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[11][i]);
      }
      randVal = rand() % 10;
      pressVal = true;
    }
    Serial.println(randVal);
    if (randVal == 0)
    {
      void zero();

    }
    else if (randVal == 1)
    {
      void one();

    }
    else if (randVal == 2)
    {
      void two();

    }
    else if (randVal == 3)
    {
      void three();

    }
    else if (randVal == 4)
    {
      void four();

    }
    else if (randVal == 5)
    {
      void five();

    }
    else if (randVal == 6)
    {
      void six();

    }
    else if (randVal == 7)
    {
      void seven();

    }
    else if (randVal == 8)
    {
      void eight();

    }
    else
    {
      void nine();

    }
  }
}

void zero()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[0][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}

void one()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[1][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}

void two()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[2][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void three()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[3][j]);
  }
  delay(250);
}
void four()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[4][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void five()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[5][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void six()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[6][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void seven()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[7][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void eight()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[8][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void nine()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[9][j]);

  }
  delay(250);
}
void turnOff()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[10][j]);
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

Comment: Does your code really compile with all these forward declarations inside a function? Also very important: `digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[11][i]);` cannot work. The first dimension of `num_array` has only 11 elements. The element with the index 11 would be the 12th. So this is reading some data outside of the array.

Comment: yes i saw that and changed it already but the mlain problem is still the same. And i changed the code to look more like the one posted underneath here

Comment: @chrisl: ("Does your code really compile with all these forward declarations inside a function?") Yes, that's the Arduino IDE: generating a main() and function declarations.

Comment: @DataFiddler I just wondered, if it is ok to declare functions inside another function. I have seen this with other languages but not with C/C++ yet

Comment: @chrisl: Now I see your concern. A declaration inside a function is accepted without error. 
But it won't work as as function call, as obviously intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, this is not an answer to your question, but I like to show some programming improvements, making your sketch  much shorter and easier to maintain.

Instead of having all functions `one`, `two`, etcetera, use a parameter to pass the number. So you get this: (I couldn't test it as I don't have an Arduino IDE at hand). Also you can use a `for` loop in the `loop` function to set the output pins.

```
int num_array[11][7] = {
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 }, // 0
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 1
  { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, // 2
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, // 3
  { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // 4
  { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 }, // 5
  { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // 6
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // 7
  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, // 8
  { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // 9
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};  //OFF

int buttonState = 0;
const int button = 12;
int randVal;
bool pressVal;

void num_Write(int);
void digit(int value);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int pin = 2; pin <= 8; pin++)
  {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  }

  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(button);
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    turnOff();
    pressVal = false;

  }
  else
  {
    if (pressVal == false)
    {
      int pin = 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
      {
        digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[11][i]);
      }
      randVal = rand() % 10;
      pressVal = true;
    }
    Serial.println(randVal);
    if ((randVal >= 0) && (randVal <= 9))
    {
      digit(randVal);
    }
  }
}

void digit(int value)
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[value][j]);
  }
  delay(250);
}

void turnOff()
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[10][j]);
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

You can also remove `turnOff` if you treat it like digit 10 but that is not so clear (or put the implementation of `digit` to another function and call it from `digit` and `turnoff`.

To solve your problem, print the values of each pin to the serial monitor. If they are correct, there is a problem in your circuit. If they are incorrect, there is a problem in your sketch. In the latter case, add more print statements until you found the exact problem.

**Update**

- Fixed void forward declaration to function call (see comment of chrisl)

If the `digit` function is never called, it means:

1. `((randVal >= 0) && (randVal <= 9))` is false, however, that is not possible since it is initialized to 0 and with the rand function it gets always values between 0 to 9.
2. pressVal is always TRUE.

So check the value of pressVal, also add (lots of) `print` statements, especiallya after each `if` and `else` so you know exactly the flow of your sketch. You will see it's very easy to find the error. If you pinpoint the problem to a `digitalRead` that is not the expected value, THAN there is high likely a problem with your circuit (a button that is never going to be LOW or HIGH). In that case, you probably forgot a pullup/pulldown resistor.

Comment: Tnx for the feedback, will try to implement this seems alot neater than my coding. any idea how it would come that the wrong segments light up?

Comment: Not sure, I would follow the tip at the end, add more print statements to be sure that the sketch is ok, and if not, check the circuit.

Comment: So i tried finding the source of my problem and it never goes to  this part of the code```void digit(int value)
{
  int pin = 2;
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    digitalWrite(pin++, num_array[value][j]);
  }
  delay(250);
} ```

Comment: Did you remove the void in `void digit(randVal);` inside the loop function? Because that is wrong, since you don't want a forward declaration of a function there.

Comment: @chrisl I should have removed it (which I did now), probably you refer to that. And you're right, copy/paste error (having no Arduino IDE at hand). Thanks for the notification.

Comment: I updated my answer to give some more tips regarding the uncalled function.